# Cross Product of two sets A and $\varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The cross product of two sets is A and B is $\{ (a,b): a \in A \text{ and } b \in B \}$

$A \times \varnothing = \{ (a,b): a \in A \text{ and } b \in \varnothing \}$

Let $A = \{ x, y, z \}$

Then $A \times \varnothing = \{ (x,\varnothing), (y,\varnothing), (z,\varnothing) \}$

But $A \times \varnothing = \varnothing$

Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "$a \in A$ and $b \in \varnothing$" is false [there is nothing in the empty set]. So $A \times \varnothing = \varnothing$ for every set $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\times B = \{(a, b) \mid a\in A \land b \in B\}$.  But in this case, we have $B = \varnothing$.  And because there are no elements $b \in \varnothing$, by definition of the empty set.

Hence there are no elements in $A \times \varnothing$, and hence, $A\times \varnothing = \varnothing.$

---

Note also that when you wrote:

> Let $A = \{ x, y, z \}.$
>
> Then $A \times \varnothing = \{ (x,\varnothing), (y,\varnothing), (z,\varnothing) \}$,

you were assuming that $\varnothing \in \varnothing$, i.e. that we can name the elements of $\varnothing$ be calling them $\varnothing.$  But by definition, the empty set has no elements.  So you're set $A \times \varnothing = \varnothing>

Answer (score 1):

The empty set is *not* a member of the empty set.  The cross product of anything with the empty set is empty.  (Cross product is sort of like multiplication, and crossing with the empty set is like multiplying by zero.)